# How to add a remainder and an integer?

Tags: java, modulo

In my code, there is a variable that gets added 29 to its original number. If that number is bigger than 31 then the variable is supposed to be reset to 0 and the remainder should be added to that. For example, we start at 4 and we are adding 29 then it's 33. And that is bigger than 31 so it should be set to 0 + 2. How can I do this in java? I have 0 clues about what to do.

Comment: That's exactly what mod (`%`) does. `val = 33 % 31;`

Comment: Technically, the `%` operator is not "mod", it's "rem". (I.e. remainder, not modulo.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you meant to do this recursively until reach a certain condition. But I think this can give you an idea

```
 public static int solution(int number){
        int add29 = (number+29);
        if(add29 > 31){
           return add29%31;
        }else{
          return add29;
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this is technically true, the answer doesn't provide an explanation about why it is working, like explaining the modulus (%) operator. Also, the `if` statement is not needed here as every number that is less then the modulus is just untouched (20 % 28 == 20).